# Does Redisson support spring-data-mongodb

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data-mongodb, redisson

So I've adding redisson to my application. The config looks like what is defined here: https://pamesh12.github.io/spring-boot/spring-cache-redis.html

singleServerConfig: address: "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"

When I try adding Cacheable to the method that call external services using RestTemplate I'm able to see the result cache in redis-cli. Though when I try adding Cacheable to service methods that call underlying Mongo repositoy I'm getting IllegalArgumentException

Could someone explain if its because its not supported? I don;t remember exactly but saw that this is supported in only pro version. And if there are any alternatives I could look at without much code change.

`ERROR com.controller.support.ExceptionController [http-nio-9006-exec-5]: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] with error Id, error code and message [[org.redisson.command.CommandAsyncService.encodeMapValue(CommandAsyncService.java:743), org.redisson.RedissonObject.encodeMapValue(RedissonObject.java:305), org.redisson.RedissonMap.fastPutOperationAsync(RedissonMap.java:1375), org.redisson.RedissonMap.fastPutAsync(RedissonMap.java:1365), org.redisson.RedissonMap.fas...`

```
@Cacheable("ratings") //cacheManager = "redisCacheManager")
public List<Entity> filterByRating(List<String> vendor/*, Pageable pageable*/) {
    
    return ratingsRepo.findByIdIn(vendor/*, pageable*/);
}
```

Config:
@Configuration
public class RedissonSpringDataConfig {

```
@Bean
public RedissonConnectionFactory
redissonConnectionFactory(RedissonClient redisson) {
    return new RedissonConnectionFactory(redisson);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public RedissonClient
redisson(@Value("classpath:redission/redisson-dev.yaml") Resource configFile)
        throws IOException {
    Config config = Config.fromYAML(configFile.getInputStream());
    return Redisson.create(config);
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redissonConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redissonConnectionFactory);
    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    return template;
}

@Bean(name = "redisCacheManager")
public CacheManager redisCacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) throws IOException {
    //String configFileName = "cache-config-" + activeProfile + ".yml";
    return new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the "IllegalArgumentException"

Comment: added details thanks